# Java loop to replace hidden word with string input

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am in a beginning Java course. The final assignment is to create a Hangman game. The rules: replace the hidden word with asterisks, then the user gets 10 attempts to guess the word. With each correct guess, we need to replace the asterisk so it looks like this d*n**.

I am having trouble creating a loop that checks the string for the letter, then replaces the string with the correct letter. Should I be using a String, char [] array, or String [] array for this? Any guidance would be MUCH APPRECIATED.

```js
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
class Hang2 {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    final int SUM = 10;

    String[] randomWords = {
      "catfish",
      "donut",
      "piano"
    };
    String word = randomWords[new Random().nextInt(randomWords.length)];
    System.out.println(word);

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("The length of your word is: ");

    String star = word;
    for (int i = 0; i < star.length(); i++) {
      System.out.print("*");
    }

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\nYou have 10 attempts to guess your word, one letter at a time. ");
    int attempts = SUM;

    String[] chars = new String[] {
      star
    };

    while (attempts > 0) {
      System.out.println("Enter a char: ");
      String letter = keyboard.nextLine();
      letter = letter.toLowerCase();
      String letterTrim = letter.trim();

      for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if (chars[i] == letterTrim) {
          chars = chars.substring(0, 4) + letterTrim + chars.substring(4 + 1);
          System.out.println(chars);


        } else if (!(chars[i] == letterTrim)) {
          attempts--;
          System.out.println("Bad guess! You have " + attempts + " attempts.");
        }

      
      }


    }

  }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant to use `star.toCharArray()`

Comment: @cricket_007  Would a char array be better than a string array or just a string in this instance? And why? Thanks!

Comment: Well, you're able to modify the characters of a char array, but not a String. For that reason, I'd say it's better.

Comment: You only need a string array at the top where you pick a random word

Answer (score -1):

Initially, it would appear lines like the following are an issue:

```
else if (!(chars[i] == letterTrim))
```

This is an issue for two reasons initially apparent to me

1. you are comparing a Character value to a String value and the two are different variable types
2. Strings are Objects and require the use of the .equals() method

it would be better here to have something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
    String letter = Character.toString(chars[i]);
    if (letter.equals(letterTrim)) {
     ...
    } else if (!letter.equals(letterTrim)) {
     ...
    }
}
```

In the above code, the Character value is converted to a String allowing you to compare the value of letter to that of letterTrim.

In Java, Strings are Objects and need to use the .equals() method to evaluate equality and not the == operator. An exception to this would be checking if a String is null. Then you would need to use the == operator like so:

```
String name = null;

if ( name == null ) {
    System.out.println("variable name is null.");
}
```

I should also add that using the == operator on Objects asserts if it is the same exact object reference and that using the assignment operator = will copy an Object reference and NOT the entire object. as an example:

```
String lastName = "Doe";
String otherLastName = lastName;

if ( lastName == otherLastName ) {
    System.out.println("lastName and otherLastName reference the same object");
}
```

Hope that has helped!

**Further information**

The example of the following was pointed out in the comments:

```
String name = "Mike";

if ( name == "Mike" ) {
    System.out.println("Same object reference");
}
```

This would print the line in the if statement. This is because the same object is referenced. That is to say "Mike" is a reference to the same object as the variable *name*. A string object is created and its reference assigned to the variable *name* on the line:

```
String name = "Mike";
```

However the following would create a new String object:

```
String name = "Mike";
String otherName = new String("Mike");

if ( name != otherName ) {
    System.out.println("Different Objects");
}

if ( name == "Mike" ) {
    System.out.println("\"Mike\" is the same Object reference as name.");
}

if ( name.equals(otherName) ) {
    System.out.println("The contents of name and otherName are equal");
}
```

The above would produce 'Different Objects', '"Mike" is the same Object reference as name', and 'The contents of name and otherName are equal'. The use of the constructor will produce (as would be expected) a new String object entirely although its contents are the same. This is why use of the .equals() method is so very important.

Comment: Please elaborate on why its better. Also, please expand on why a String needs == with an example.

Comment: Updated. Thank you for the guidance!

Comment: @Mike So, if i set name to `"Mike"` and then do `name == "Mike"` what will happen?

Comment: `String[] chars`... Please tell me what is a Character here?

Comment: @cricket_007 apologies, I changed String chars to: String chars = new String {word}; So the character should be one from the random word generated

Comment: @Meesh that's still a String, not a `char[]`

Comment: I changed the string into a char array and I also converted the user guess from a string to a char. I continue to get the error: char cannot be dereferenced
 if (newChar[i].equals(charLetter)) {